# Why do base R and dplyr::arrange() give different row names in output

Tags: r, dplyr

Goal: to get new row names when using base R order() function (as is done with `dplyr::arrange()`). The rownames/index output for the base R call is 3, 1, 2 as seen below whereas the output for arrange() is 1, 2, 3 (seen below). How can I get 1, 2, 3 using base R order()?

Reprex:

```
library(dplyr)


df <- data.frame(
  company = c("A", "B", "C"),
  sales = c(100, 200, 50)
)

# base R:

df[order(df$sales),]

# dplyr:

arrange(df, sales)
```

```
# Base R output:

##   company sales
## 3       C    50
## 1       A   100
## 2       B   200

# dplyr output:

##   company sales
## 1       C    50
## 2       A   100
## 3       B   200
```

Comment: Do you want to return original row numbers to return in dplyr way?

Comment: Most `dplyr` (and `tibble`) functions intentionally remove row names. After some research, one compelling argument is *"There's no notion of a "row name" in database management systems or, say, CSV or Excel files."* (https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/272#issuecomment-310539998).

Comment: Following r2evals comment, also see "why row names are undesirable" from Hadly Wickham's Advanced R https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html?q=rownames#rownames for the official explanation "For these reasons, tibbles do not support row names"

Comment: So while this might be unexpected to you, it is intentional from the devs, and unlikely to change. If you need to preserve the information in the row names, then I suggest either `tibble::rownames_to_column` or `tibble::rowid_to_column` to store that information in an explicit column.

Comment: I see, thanks. The arguments are compelling and it makes perfect sense to me. I hope it doesn't change. This is why tidyverse is great.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this behavior is intentional and documented.

Comment: But is it possible to get the same output (row names: 1, 2, 3) using base R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to the same rownames as what result after `arrange()`, you can assign the row names after using `order()`.

```
df_new <- df[order(df$sales),]
rownames(df_new) <- 1:nrow(df_new)
```

It may be good practice to create an ID column instead of using row names. Usually numbered ID's correspond to the original data, but of course you can create them after your ordering operation.

```
df_new <- df[order(df$sales),]
df_new$id <- 1:nrow(df_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is for the row numbers after using `arrange()` to match what you get from `order()`, then do the following (a few extra `dplyr` and `tibble` steps).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df %>%
   rownames_to_column() %>%
   arrange(sales) %>%
   column_to_rownames("rowname")

  company sales
3       C    50
1       A   100
2       B   200
```